# Node module versioning

Tags: npm, node-modules, versioning, semantic-versioning

I have a node module for example `demo-npm-module`. The module has different versions published to npm. For example

```
1.0.0
1.1.0
2.0.0
3.0.0
```

I want to make some bug fix in an older version for example `1.1.0` , then the version will be updated to `1.1.1`. I made this change and published to npm. Now the problem is after publishing version `1.1.1` this becomes the latest version.
If I do `npm install demo-npm-module` now it will install version `1.1.1` instead of the actual latest version which is `3.0.0`.

Is there any solution to publish changes to an older version and increment the patch/minor version number of node package without making it the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [`npm publish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish).

By default, `npm` assigns the tag `latest` to the release you publish.

An by default, `npm install` looks up for the version containing tag `latest`.

You can work around this by defining your own tag, in such case, you may use `v1` for the whole set of versions `1.x.y`.

```
npm publish --tag v1
```

Mike Bostock, a javascript developer, wrote an article detailing this a while ago, it's worth having a look at it: [Prereleases and Npm](https://medium.com/@mbostock/prereleases-and-npm-e778fc5e2420).